how long does it take for grub to load?
I am a new user of Linux. how long does it take for grub to load and long is too long. I am running Linux thru a USB drive and the device is a Toshiba protege R705 that had windows 7 (before I removed the hard drive). the port that the drive is plugged into is not a USB 3.0 port. the os on the USB drive is Ubuntu 24_0

USB2 will be slow.  What type of USB install?  If a persistent live media, you can at least add the "toram" to run faster from memory after the boot (which will unfortunately be even slower to set up the ramdisk).

While I still have multiple flash drives with full installs, I now use a external SSD drive. Found it made my very old 2006 era laptop functional with Kubuntu. That laptop would not install Ubuntu as it was too much. But lighter weight flavors worked. What flavor are you using?  https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours
Light weight flavors:
Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Budgie
Flavors of Ubuntu only come with three years of supported life (five years applies to Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server but not flavors)

There is no Ubuntu 24_0; standard Ubuntu releases are year.month in format and 0 is an invalid/incomplete month. There are also snap only releases of Ubuntu that use the year format (eg. Ubuntu Core 24 being the 2024 release), but they don't have a _0 attached.  Grub has multiple components, and options will vary, but USB flash media is serial and thus rather slow

The USB stick speed plays a significant role in determining the boot time of Ubuntu from a Live USB. Since the port is USB 2.0, which has a maximum theoretical transfer rate of 480 Mbps, it will be slower than USB 3.0 or newer.
Some specifics:

A USB stick with a read/write speed of 170 Mb/s (approximately 13.3 Mbps) took around 2 minutes to boot.
A USB stick with a slower read/write speed (not specified) could take twice as long, approximately 4 minutes.
Adding a persistent partition to the USB stick can significantly slow down the boot process, potentially taking up to 32 minutes (as seen in one example).

Considering the USB 2.0 port’s slower transfer rate, it’s likely that the boot time will be longer than what’s seen with faster USB ports. However, without more specific information about the USB stick’s read/write speed, it’s difficult to provide an exact estimate.
As a conservative estimate, assuming a slower-than-average USB stick, it’s possible that Ubuntu might take around 4-6 minutes to boot from a Live USB using a USB 2.0 port. However, this is a rough estimate and actual boot times may vary depending on the specific hardware and USB stick used.
